# vba Outlook create an email based on a userform's data and a template

Tags: vba, email, templates, outlook

I'm would like to create a macro that will :

1) Generate a userform asking for info

2) Display a template filled with the info just written in the userform

To do that, I was wondering if it was possible to use bookmarks like in Word. I would create a mail template with bookmarks and I could just replace them in the validation_click() event of the userform. I don't find any example on the Web and the bookmarks don't seem to work like in Word (they don't appear that way "[bookmark1]")

Thank you for your help

Comment: Try a unique placeholder https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20130422/vb-outlook-macro-how-to-put-variable-fields-in-an-email-template

Answer (score 0):

You may consider creating a template in Outlook. The SaveAs method of the MailItem allows to save the item as a template on the disk:

```
 Sub CreateTemplate() 
  Dim MyItem As Outlook.MailItem 

  Set MyItem = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem) 
  MyItem.Subject = "Status Report" 
  MyItem.To = "Eugene Astafiev" 
  MyItem.Display 
  MyItem.SaveAs Environ("HOMEPATH") &; "\My Documents\statusrep.oft", OlSaveAsType.olTemplate 
 End Sub
```

In the template you can define placeholders that can be replaced later (when a new item is created). The [CreateItemFromTemplate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/application-createitemfromtemplate-method-outlook) method of the Application class creates a new Microsoft Outlook item from an Outlook template (.oft) and returns the new item.

```
Sub CreateFromTemplate() 
 Dim MyItem As Outlook.MailItem 

 Set MyItem = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\statusrep.oft", _ 
   Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDrafts)) 
 MyItem.Save 
End Sub
```

You may find the [How To: Create a new Outlook message based on a template](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/08/31/outlook-create-message-based-on-template/) article helpful.

P.S. Outlook uses Word as an email editor. So, you can use the Word object model when dealing with item bodies. See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012(v=office.12).aspx) for more information.